# Matching a word with a specified character inside it but not on its borders

Tags: regex

How to find/match whole words where there may be one or more dashes but only inside the word - not on the boundaries?

Correct:

```
w
wo
w-o
wo-r-d
```

Not correct/rejected:

```
-
-w
w-
-word
wo-rd-
```

I've tried several patterns on https://regex101.com but they all fail

Comment: If you're matching inside a text and your regex flavour supports atomic grouping, something like `(?<!-)\b[\w-]++\b(?!-)` would probably work, since matched hyphens can't be given up to escape the negative lookahead, making the expression fail on words bounded by hyphens.

Comment: If you're matching entire lines, something like `^\w(?:[\w-]*\w)?$` should also work, which is a word of either length 1 or at least length two, as long as there are word characters at the boundaries and word characters or hyphens between them.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/nMxWdm/1):

```
^(\w|\w[\w-]*\w)$
```

The above pattern matches:

- a single word character (`\w`), OR
- a single word character, followed by as many word or dash characters, until it reaches the final word character

`\w` matches any word character (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). If you wish to have only letter, use `[a-zA-Z]` instead.

Comment: No need for the lazy quantifier; you're matching that class until the end of the line anyway, might as well get there as quickly as possible. Edit: "the `[\w-]*?` is greedy" is actually specifically wrong with the lazy quantifier `?`.

Comment: Thanks @oriberu. A mistake indeed. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Given only dashes are allowed characters within strings, you can use the following regex:

```
^[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z\-]*[A-Za-z])?(?=\s|$)
```

Regex Explanation:

- `^`: start of string symbol
- `[A-Za-z]`: a character (enforces word to start with a letter)
- `(?:[A-Za-z\-]*[A-Za-z])?`: optional combination of other characters and dashes, ensuring that last symbol is a character
- `(?=\s|$)`: a space or end of string symbol (ensures your word has ended)

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fPRFfa/1).

Comment: Thanks, I actually had a very similar idea. https://regex101.com/r/wiK9Ze/1